# Editing hybrid_property fields in flask-admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I'm trying to have editable hybrid_property fields in `flask-admin`, but they're not showing up in the create or edit views. They do show up in the list view though. I've tried setting `ignore_hidden=False` but that isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
class TestTable(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "test_table"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    _test_column = db.Column(db.String)

    @hybrid_property
    def test_column(self):
        return self._test_column

    @test_column.setter
    def test_column(self, test_column):
        self._test_column = test_column


class TestModelView(ModelView):
    ignore_hidden = False


admin = Admin(app, name="TestHybrid")
admin.add_view(TestModelView(TestTable, db.session))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make it editable by adding **test_column** to **form_extra_fields** as follows:

```
from wtforms.fields import StringField

class TestModelView(ModelView):
    form_extra_fields = {
        'test_column': StringField('test_column')
    }
```

After saving test one with value 'test1' in admin panel:

```
>>> TestTable.query.all()[-1]._test_column
'test1'
>>> TestTable.query.all()[-1].test_column
'test1'
```

**test_column** field is visible in edit and create views.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. `TextField` should be switched to `StringField` since it is soon to be deprecated though

Comment: Good point, I changed it. Please accept the answer if you find it useful  .